# Spring Integration: Message Driven Channel Adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

As per the documentation int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter uses SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor

SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor doesn't reuse threads and creates a new thread for each task. In case of message-driven-channel-adapter what is the definition of  a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of message driven channel Adapter the task is a constantly polling loop. So, this is going to be a long- living resource which keeps thread active. Therefore we don’t care too much about source of threads. See Spring JMS for more information.